# Error LNK1169 with Qt Creator

Tags: qt, linker-errors

first of all, please don't be too hard on me, I am truly a newbie at using Qt and programming is not really my best so I will try to make it as clear as possible.

Here is my configuration:

- Windows XP
- Visual Studio 2008
- Qt 4.7.4
- Qt Creator 2.2.1
- OpenCV 2.3.1
- NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit CUDA 4.0
- A library of my own (actually of my beloved intern) named CaROLlib.

To use the library that he programed with Visual Studio 2008, my intern programed an interface named InterfaceCaROL, using Qt Creator. He finished on his side and sent all the sources, CaROLlib and InterfaceCaROL, to me (we are working at a 16 000km distance). On his computer everything works fine.

I built CaROLlib in Debug using Visual Studio 2008.
I redefined in the .pro the paths needed by InterfaceCaROL.
I tried to build in Debug and obtained the following Build Issues:

- warnings:

  - > c:\carol\include\Filter.h:45: warning: C4100: 'other' : unreferenced formal parameter
  - > C:\Documents and Settings\Renan\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp:312: warning: C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
  - > C:\Documents and Settings\Renan\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp:366: warning: C4129: '.' : unrecognized character escape sequence
  - > C:\Documents and Settings\Renan\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp:436: warning: C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
  - > C:\Documents and Settings\Renan\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp:442: warning: C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
  - > C:\Documents and Settings\Renan\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp:494: warning: C4129: '.' : unrecognized character escape sequence
  - > :-1: warning: LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
  - > :-1: warning: LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
  - > :-1: warning: LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
- error:

  - > debug\InterfaceCaROL.exe:-1: error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

I carefully used the Debug version of all the libraries I am using (OpenCV, CaROLlib). I have only a doubt with CUDA since there is no choice (meaning no cudart.lib and cudartd.lib).

Does anyone have an idea? Did anyone ever encountered the same problem? Did he/she solved it?

Here follows a sample of my code:

- in the .pro:

  ```
  HEADERS += \
      mockinterfacecarol.h

  SOURCES += \
      mockinterfacecarol.cpp \
      main.cpp

  FORMS += \
      mockinterfacecarol.ui



  win32: LIBS += qaxcontainer.lib


  win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../CaROL/lib/ -lCaROLlibd

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../CaROL/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../CaROL/include

  win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../CaROL/lib/CaROLlibd.lib


  win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../"Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit"/CUDA/v4.0/lib/Win32/ -lcudart

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../"Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit"/CUDA/v4.0/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../"Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit"/CUDA/v4.0/include

  win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../"Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit"/CUDA/v4.0/lib/Win32/cudart.lib


  win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/x86/vc9/lib/ -lopencv_core231d

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include
  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include/opencv2
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include/opencv2

  win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_core231d.lib


  win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/x86/vc9/lib/ -lopencv_highgui231d

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include
  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include/opencv2
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include/opencv2

  win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_highgui231d.lib


  win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/x86/vc9/lib/ -lopencv_imgproc231d

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include
  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include/opencv2
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/include/opencv2

  win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV2.3.1/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_imgproc231d.lib
  ```
- in the main:

  ```
  #include <QApplication>    
  #include <QGridLayout>    
  #include <QSpinBox>    
  #include <QSlider>    
  #include <QFileDialog>    
  #include "mockinterfacecarol.h"    
  #include "ui_testradiobutton.h"

  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
         QApplication app(argc, argv);
         MockInterfaceCarol* m = new MockInterfaceCarol;
         m->show();

         return app.exec();    
  }
  ```
- in mockinterfacecarol

  ```
  #include "mockinterfacecarol.h"
  #include "carolcpp.h"
  #include "opencv.hpp"
  #include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
  #include <QMessageBox>
  #include <QAxWidget>

  MockInterfaceCarol::MockInterfaceCarol(QWidget *parent) :
      QMainWindow(parent)
  {
      setupUi(this);
      etc...
  ```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Cheers,

Antoine

If needed, here is the compiler output:

```
Running build steps for project InterfaceCaROL...
Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" clean
    C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -nologo -j 2 -f Makefile.Release clean
    del release\moc_mockinterfacecarol.cpp
    del ui_mockinterfacecarol.h
    del release\mockinterfacecarol.obj release\main.obj release\moc_mockinterfacecarol.obj
    del release\InterfaceCaROL.intermediate.manifest release\InterfaceCaROL.exp
    C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -nologo -j 2 -f Makefile.Debug clean

jom 1.0.4 - empower your cores

Could Not Find C:\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop\release\moc_mockinterfacecarol.cpp
Could Not Find C:\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop\release\mockinterfacecarol.obj
Could Not Find C:\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop\release\InterfaceCaROL.intermediate.manifest
    del debug\moc_mockinterfacecarol.cpp
    del ui_mockinterfacecarol.h
    del debug\mockinterfacecarol.obj debug\main.obj debug\moc_mockinterfacecarol.obj
    del debug\InterfaceCaROL.intermediate.manifest debug\InterfaceCaROL.exp debug\InterfaceCaROL.ilk vc*.pdb vc*.idb
    del ".\InterfaceCaROL.intermediate.manifest"
    del InterfaceCaROL.exp
Could Not Find C:\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop\ui_mockinterfacecarol.h
Could Not Find C:\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop\InterfaceCaROL.intermediate.manifest
    del InterfaceCaROL.ilk
    del vc*.pdb
    del vc*.idb
Could Not Find C:\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop\InterfaceCaROL.exp
Could Not Find C:\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop\InterfaceCaROL.ilk
Could Not Find C:\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop\vc*.pdb
Could Not Find C:\Projects\InterfaceCaROL-build-desktop\vc*.idb
The process "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -nologo -j 2 -f Makefile.Debug
    c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\bin\uic.exe ..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.ui -o ui_mockinterfacecarol.h
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include" -I"c:\CaROL\include" -I"c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include\opencv2" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include\opencv2" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include\opencv2" -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\InterfaceCaROL" -I"." -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fodebug\ @C:\LOCALS~1\Temp\mockinterfacecarol.obj.2760.328.jom
mockinterfacecarol.cpp
c:\carol\include\Filter.h(45) : warning C4100: 'other' : unreferenced formal parameter
..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp(312) : warning C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp(366) : warning C4129: '.' : unrecognized character escape sequence
..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp(436) : warning C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp(442) : warning C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.cpp(494) : warning C4129: '.' : unrecognized character escape sequence
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include" -I"c:\CaROL\include" -I"c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include\opencv2" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include\opencv2" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include\opencv2" -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\InterfaceCaROL" -I"." -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fodebug\ @C:\LOCALS~1\Temp\main.obj.2760.672.jom
main.cpp
    C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT @debug/mocinclude.tmp -D_MSC_VER=1500 -DWIN32 ..\InterfaceCaROL\mockinterfacecarol.h -o debug\moc_mockinterfacecarol.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include" -I"c:\CaROL\include" -I"c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include\opencv2" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include\opencv2" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include" -I"c:\OpenCV2.3.1\build\include\opencv2" -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\InterfaceCaROL" -I"." -I"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fodebug\ @C:\DOCUME~1\Renan\LOCALS~1\Temp\moc_mockinterfacecarol.obj.2760.10344.jom
moc_mockinterfacecarol.cpp
    link /LIBPATH:"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\msvc2008\lib" /NOLOGO /DEBUG /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"debug\InterfaceCaROL.intermediate.manifest" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /OUT:debug\InterfaceCaROL.exe @C:\LOCALS~1\Temp\InterfaceCaROL.exe.2760.14281.jom
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Clg.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char const * __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::c_str(void)const " (?c_str@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEPBDXZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Clg.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & (__cdecl*)(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &))" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@P6AAAV01@AAV01@@Z@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::endl(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?endl@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@AAV21@@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Clg.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::width(int)" (?width@ios_base@std@@QAEHH@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,int)" (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHPBDH@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static bool __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::eq_int_type(int const &,int const &)" (?eq_int_type@?$char_traits@D@std@@SA_NABH0@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static int __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::eof(void)" (?eof@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAHXZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char)" (?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(void)const " (?rdbuf@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDXZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (?width@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static unsigned int __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::length(char const *)" (?length@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAIPBD@Z) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Clg.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::tie(void)const " (?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::good(void)const " (?good@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::locale::facet * __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Decref(void)" (?_Decref@facet@locale@std@@QAEPAV123@XZ) already defined in CaROLlibd.lib(Utilities.cu.obj)
libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _AtModuleExit(void (__cdecl*)(void))" (?_AtModuleExit@@YAXP6AXXZ@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: __Fac_tidy already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::locale::facet::facet_Register(class std::locale::facet *)" (?facet_Register@facet@locale@std@@CAXPAV123@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_dtor(class std::_Locinfo *)" (?_Locinfo_dtor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Init(void)" (?_Init@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(class std::_Locinfo *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?_Locinfo_ctor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Addstd(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Addstd@ios_base@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Ios_base_dtor(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Ios_base_dtor@ios_base@std@@CAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(setlocal.obj) : error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(lconv.obj) : error LNK2005: _localeconv already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __decode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter_noinfo already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj) : error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(_ctype.obj) : error LNK2005: _isupper already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj) : error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
debug\InterfaceCaROL.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

jom 1.0.4 - empower your cores

command failed with exit code 1169
command failed with exit code 2
The process "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project InterfaceCaROL (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Comment: Can you post all of the linker output? [LNK1169](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xttf5w7w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) should be preceded by LNK2005.

Comment: @hmjd: 

I edited my topic to add all the outputs you were asking for. Hope it helps. However, I did not see any LNK2005. My LNK1169 is preceded by three LNK4098.

Comment: @hmjd: my bad, I just looked more accurately at the Compiler Output and saw indeed loads of LNK2005... Still, I don't really know what it means. I understand it is a problem of library link order but... From other posts around that topic, I understand it may be a problem with my compilation of Qt. Is it?

Comment: From the errors it appears the VC runtime has been statically linked into the objects that comprise `CaROLlibd.lib`. Rebuild `CaROLlibd.lib` and don't statically link the runtime.

Comment: @hmjd: I am sorry but I don't really understand your comment and I don't really know how to do it. Do you mean that in the _Properties_ of the project, in _C/C++_, _Code Generation_, _Runtime Library_ I have to do some changes? And in the same _Properties_, in the _CUDA Runtime API_, do I have to change anything? I tried that, nothing better happened... What does __don't statically link the runtime__ mean?